# near "in": syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to run this code but I get the following error... 
Actually, I am trying Face Recognition using OpenCV..

```
import sqlite3
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request as ur
faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

def insert(ID,Name):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("FaceBase.db")
    cmd="SELECT * FROM People Where id=?"+str(id)
    cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
    doesRecordExist=0
    for row in cursor:
        doesRecordExist=1
    if(doesRecordExist==1):
        cmd="UPDATE People SET Name="+str(Name)+"WHERE Id="+str(ID)
    else:
        cmd="INSERT INTO People(ID,Name) Values("+str(ID)+","+str(Name)+")"
    conn.execute(cmd)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

But I got this Error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Sandesh R Patil/Desktop/Project/Face Recog 
sqlite/datasetCreator.py", line 10, in insert
    cursor=conn.execute(cmd)

OperationalError: near "in": syntax error
```

Comment: You might want to read up on "sql injection" before you write much more SQL code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID on Line 9 is incorrect try this:

```
import sqlite3
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request as ur
faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

def insert(ID,Name):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("FaceBase.db")
    cmd="SELECT * FROM People WHERE id=?"+str(ID)
    cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
    doesRecordExist=0
    for row in cursor:
        doesRecordExist=1
    if(doesRecordExist==1):
        cmd="UPDATE People SET Name="+str(Name)+" WHERE Id="+str(ID)
    else:
        cmd="INSERT INTO People(ID,Name) Values("+str(ID)+","+str(Name)+")"
    conn.execute(cmd)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: and what is that ?

Comment: I tried the code that you suggested..                                                                       But now there's a new error..       It says : OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Comment: @Sandesh.Patil I don't see '<' operator in the above snippet, could you provide the line on which this error has occurred?

Comment: there isn't any '<' operator in my code. The error has occurred on line no 10: cursor=conn.execute(cmd)... The error is on same line as previous one the only difference is "in" has changed to "<"...

Comment: @Sandesh.Patil Check the value of ID, just print it prior to execute & if that's fine(just an integer) print cmd

Comment: Hey, I just found out that this was clearly my fault! No need to worry.. On the Line no. 9, I had typed 'id' instead of 'ID'.. When I  corrected this, the error automatically got resolved. Sorry for inconvenience buddy ;)

Comment: My answer said that :). if it solved your problem, kindly mark it as the answer.